# Is this function convex or concave on $(x,y,z)$?

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Is this function convex or concave on $(x,y,z)$? $A$, $B$, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive constants.

$$f(x,y,z) = A\exp\left(\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}\right) + B\exp\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)$$

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: It is for my master research. I need to show that has a unique solution.

Comment: Umm... that *what* has a unique solution?

Comment: these are Euclidean distances and subject to some constraints.

Comment: It is hard to show that the hessian is a PSD matirx

Comment: If 1-d concepts generalize to 3-d then [using this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) you see that if $f$ and $g$ are convex so is $f+g$, and if $f$ is convex so is $e^f$. So your function will be convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The Euclidean norm $x\mapsto |x|$ (and any norm for that matter) is a convex function. This follows from the definition of a norm.
2. If $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is convex and $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a convex nondecreasing function, then the composition $\phi\circ f$ is also convex. This is immediate from the definition of convexity used twice.
3. The sum of two convex functions is convex.